# Как пользоваться методом Focus()?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Здравствуйте всем, есть контрол webBrowser, на нём есть код пример:

```
<a href = "http://yandex.ru">Это Яндекс!</a>
```

И мне нужно сделать проверку:

Если переменная начинается на("http://yandex"){
 значит сфокусироваться на этом елементе.
}

Дело в том, что как сделать условия проверки строки я сделал, а вот как сфокусировать не понял. Смотрел на MSDN там, что-то вообще маленькая статья по этому поводу я ничего не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам додумался как сделать такое, для тех кому интересно пишу здесь код.

```
HtmlElementCollection elemet = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("a");

foreach(HtmlElement elem in element)
{
 string link = elem.GetAttribute("href");

 if(link.StartWith("http://yandex"))
 {  
  elem.Focus();
 }
}
```